# Math Modeling confusions

Tags: mathematical-modeling

In the story Gulliver’s Travels (read the Wikipedia page if you’ve never heard of it), the 6-inch tall Lilliputians imprison and tie up Gulliver. Reasoning that he is 12 times their height, they feed him $12^3 = 1728$ times the volume that an average Lilliputian ate. Why was this not a good estimate? Give a better estimate.

I am confused about how to construct a relationship between height and food consumption. So I tried to solve it by using the power law.

Comment: I don't have any particular thoughts on the question, but why do you assume it isn't a good estimate? Also bear in mind this is a work of fiction so if there are values given in the book they might simply be wrong.

Comment: Additionally any errors are going to come down to biology (of fictional entities) so you would probably be better off asking somewhere more oriented towards that.